# use Schwarz inequality to get $\int_x^{+\infty }f(t) dt \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, inequality

$f(x)\ge 0,\forall x\in \Bbb R$. If

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) dx =1, \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x) dx =0,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2f(x) dx =1. $$

Show that , for every $x\gt0$,
$$\int_x^{+\infty }f(t) dt \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

---

I have a method: proof by contradiction

If $a\gt0$ such that $\int_a^{+\infty }f(t) dt \gt \frac{1}{1+a^2}$, then

$$ \int_{a}^{+\infty}xf(x) dx \gt \dfrac{a}{1+a^2},\int_{a}^{+\infty}x^2f(x) dx \gt\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}. $$

so

$$\int_{-\infty}^a f(x) dx \lt -\dfrac{a^2}{1+a^2}, \int_{-\infty}^a xf(x) dx \lt -\dfrac{a}{1+a^2},\int_{-\infty}^a x^2f(x) dx \lt\frac{1}{1+a^2}. $$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^a (ax+1)^2f(x) dx \lt a^2 \frac{1}{1+a^2}-2a\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}=0. $$

I heard that the inequality is related to probability theory，and **it can't be improved, how to cite a function to get this?  Are there any other methods, use Schwarz inequality**?

Comment: It looks to me like you assumed $f(-x)=f(x)$ which is not given here.

Comment: @lan No, don't assumed $f(-x)=f(x)$

Comment: Never mind, I see how it goes, you didn't invert $a$, so it makes sense.

Comment: Or rather it basically makes sense...your right sides in the second to last line are in backwards order, but they all get added together anyway.

Comment: Hi @ziangchen , if I have an approach using the Schwarz inequality, should I post it as a separate answer or edit my current answer? I am.asking because the approaches are different, but also because I already have an answer and so I can link both approaches if I post the two approaches together

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  as you like.  many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, ziang. I plan to edit my existing answer.

Comment: @ziangchen I have added a proof using Cauchy-Schwarz. I borrowed the minimizer $\frac 1x$ from the first proof : if I did not know about that, then I'd have used a variable $u$ in place of it, and the same argument would apply, with me minimizing in terms of $u$ later, like in the first proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

##### What does this have to do with probability?

It is true that this falls under the realm of probability theory, because if $X$ is a real valued random variable with density $f(x)$ i.e. $P(X \in (a,b)) = \int_a^b f(x)dx$ for all $a<b$, then :

- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ assert that $f$ is a well-defined density and $X$ a well defined random variable.
- $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx = 0$ is equivalent to $E[X] = 0$.
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x)dx = 1$ is equivalent to $E[X^2] = 1$,which when combined with the previous statement , gives $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = 1-0=1$.
- $\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t)dt = P(X \geq x)$ for $x>0$, which we write as $P(X - E[X] \geq x)$ for reasons becoming clear later.
- $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X)+x^2}$.

Thus, the inequality in probabilistic terms, is $P(X - E[X] \geq x) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X) + x^2}$ for every $x >0$.  This is called the *Cantelli inequality*. It is tight, by using the random variable $X$ given by a Bernoulli random variable with any parameter $p$, and taking its density.

##### A proof without using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

I will translate the probabilistic proof into a proof without such  terminology. Fix $f$ and $x >0$. We have , for any $u \geq 0$ :
$$
\int_{x}^\infty f(t)dt \leq \int_x^\infty f(t)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{-x} f(t)dt \\= \int_{x+u}^\infty f(t-u)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{-x-u} f(t-u)dt
$$

and now we introduce $x+u$ into both integrals. By domination , since $\frac{t^2}{(x+u)^2} \geq 1$ for every $|t| \geq x+u$:
$$
\int_{x+u}^\infty f(t-u)dt \leq \frac{1}{(x+u)^2} \int_{x+u}^{\infty} t^2f(t-u)dt \\
\int_{\infty}^{-x-u} f(t-u)dt \leq \frac{1}{(x+u)^2} \int_{-\infty}^{-x-u} t^2f(t-u)dt
$$

and adding them gives:
$$
\int_{x+u}^\infty f(t-u)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{-x-u} f(t-u)dt\\ \leq \frac{1}{(x+u)^2} \int_{x+u}^{\infty} t^2f(t-u)dt + \frac{1}{(x+u)^2} \int_{-\infty}^{-x-u} t^2f(t-u)dt \\
\leq \frac 1{(x+u)^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2f(t-u)dt =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t+u)^2f(t)dt
 $$

which upon expansion and simplification becomes $$
\int_x^\infty f(t)dt \leq \frac{1 + u^2}{(x+u)^2}
$$

for every $u \geq 0$. So the best bound is when the right hand side is minimized i.e. the $u \geq 0$ for which $\frac{1+u^2}{(x+u)^2}$ is minimal. This can be done e.g. using differentiation : differentiating w.r.t $u$ gives $\frac{2(xu-1)}{(x+u)^3}$, which is zero when $u=\frac 1x$. One can check the second derivative is positive at this point. At $u = \frac 1x$ we have $\frac{1 + u^2}{(x+u)^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ , as desired.

##### A proof using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz (-Буняковский) inequality, in the context of integrals, states that :

> If $f,g$ are square-integrable functions on $(a,b)$ for any $a<b$ possibly infinite, then $fg$ is integrable on $(a,b)$ and $$
> \left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx \right| \leq \sqrt{\int_{a}^b f(x)^2dx} \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} g(x)^2dx}
> $$

To use this correctly, we must play around a little with the start, use Cauchy-Schwarz, and then correct the changes.

So let's start with $f$ as in the question and $x>0$. Our intuition for the change of variable in the next step is derived from the previous proof : recall the minimizer $\frac 1x$.

We write :
$$
\int_{x}^\infty f(t)dt = \int_{x+\frac 1x} f\left(t - \frac 1x\right)dt \\
\leq \int_{x+\frac 1x}^\infty f\left(t-\frac 1x\right)\frac{t}{x + \frac 1x} dt 
$$

where the inequality follows because $\frac{t}{x+\frac 1x} \geq 1$ whenever $t \geq x + \frac 1x$, so a domination of integrand occurs.

Finally, for the Cauchy Schwarz split :
$$
\int_{x+\frac 1x}^\infty f\left(t-\frac 1x\right)\frac{t}{x + \frac 1x} dt  = \int_{x+\frac 1x}^{\infty} \left[t\sqrt{f\left(t-\frac 1x\right)}\right]\left[\frac{\sqrt{f(t-\frac 1x)}}{(x+\frac 1x)}\right] dt
$$

applying it (on the second line : the first line is just what we know from before) :
$$
\int_{x}^\infty f(t)dt \leq \int_{x+\frac 1x}^\infty f\left(t-\frac 1x\right)\frac{t}{x + \frac 1x} dt \\ \leq \sqrt{\int_{x+\frac 1x}^{\infty} t^2f\left(t-\frac 1x\right)dt}\sqrt{ \int_{x+\frac 1x}^{\infty} \frac{f\left(t - \frac 1x\right)}{(x+\frac 1x)^2}dt}\\ = \frac 1{x+\frac 1x} \sqrt{\int_{x}^\infty (t +1/x)^2 f(t)dt} \sqrt{\int_x^\infty f(t)dt}
$$

take the $\sqrt{\int_x^\infty f(t)dt}$ to the other side and square both sides to get :
$$
\int_x^\infty f(t)dt \leq \frac{\int_{x}^{\infty} (t+\frac 1x)^2f(t) dt}{(x+\frac 1x)^2} \leq \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t+\frac 1x)^2 f(t)dt}{(x+\frac 1x)^2}
 \\
= \frac 1{(x+\frac 1x)^2} \left(1 + \frac 1{x^2}\right) = \frac 1{1+x^2}$$

after simplification, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a million

Comment: @ziangchen You are welcome! If you are satisfied, you may use the bounty. Otherwise you can seek further clarification.

Comment: @ziangchen Thank you very much! You will be surprised to know how many analytical identities have counterparts in probability that are easier to prove! This interchangeability between the two often allows for utterly beautiful proofs of otherwise analytically difficult looking propositions.