# Show that $\mu(\{x \in X \colon f(x)> \alpha\}) \leq \frac{1}{1 + \alpha^2}$ for all $\alpha > 0 $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu (X) = 1$ and $f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable such that $f \in L^2(\mu)$, $\int_{X}f d\mu =0$ and $\int_{X}f^2 d\mu = 1$. Show that $\mu(\{x \in X \colon f(x)> \alpha\}) \leq 1/(1 + \alpha^2)$ for all $\alpha >0$

I've been trying to solve this problem for many hours, but nothing good has come of it. I restrict myself to uploading my attempts because they do not add up to anything interesting, instead I would like to know a simple and less cumbersome test like my ideas and improve my reasoning. I appreciate any response you can give me.

Comment: this is the one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality (aka Cantelli's inequality), just with measure theory notation instead of probability notation

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4226764/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom  Thanks. I have edited the title.

Comment: Cantelli's inequality! I proved this specifically for measures with density $f$ over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992881/use-schwarz-inequality-to-get-int-x-infty-ft-dt-leq-frac11x2/3992926#3992926).  Replace $f(x)dx$ with the measure $f(x)d \mu$ and integrate over subsets of the sample space instead. One can pull it off without too much difficulty.